# Django orm and path import

Tags: django, orm, import, path

Here is my file tree :

--script

..........script.py

-- emails

.........**__*init*__**.py

.........models.py

settings.py

_***init*_**.py

manage.py

and my code in script.py

```
import email, getpass, imaplib, os
import datetime
import unicodedata
import time
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "../settings")
import sys
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath("../")
sys.path.append(cmd_folder)
from emails.models import Email
```

but i have this error :

```
TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument
```

How to resolve it please ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/..')
```

Comment: Still : TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument

Answer (score 0):

The solution thanks to #django

../ is incorrect for module path so :

```
import sys
cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/../..')
sys.path.append(cmd_folder)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Sumomo.settings")
from Sumomo.emails.models import Email
```

(sumomo is the name of my project)